# Autodesk forge viewer Setting style to edging in chrome display error

Tags: google-chrome, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

When I run the following command in my Chrome console the viewer gets black rectangles covering it (sometimes in a L-like shape). Apparently running it on any page with a viewer causes the error. This is causing errors with part of our product.

NOP_VIEWER.impl.setPostProcessParameter("style", "edging");

Viewer version: 6.5 - I was also able to replicate in 6.6.
Chrome Version: Version 75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Seems to work in older versions of Chrome

[image: image of error]

Comment: Can confirm to be able to reproduce the issue - we are checking with the Engineering team and will get back to you soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've fixed this and pushed a patch to production.  Please try again in version 6.6.4.

Comment: Chrome 75 introduces changes to the canvas:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/06/nic75?utm_medium=email&utm_source=topic+optin&utm_campaign=engagement&utm_content=20190612+web+nl&mkt_tok=eyJpIjoiTXpWbFpUazFPREF5TnpNMyIsInQiOiI2Mlh1ZG1VUUMxV1VzT3ppZldvR2pmOThnZlwvNTc0citwQ09HekhVQ3ZuNkFCRjBoaEZaYTZrRmJLcHhGQTRGaWYxZUppNjhVa2xvR2xMV3ZTZTI0YU01Y2lPTk5qcE50bVZ4ZTBHT203XC9lYWMreUdGZTNPMDhHZjJsaFJLaVE5In0%3D